# How to separate numbers from a string?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a string coming from database in a format like

> "2,5,5,3"

.
What i am trying to do is, i want to separate every int from this string and assign in a new variable.
Than, on the basis if it i want to show images.
For ex: 
i have 5 image views named as

> img1,img2,img3 etc

so if i get output from db as "3,2,4 "

than i want to show img3, img2 and img4.
So my images depends on the returned string.
How can i move forward in order to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this

```
img1.hidden=YES;
img2.hidden=YES;
img3.hidden=YES;
img4.hidden=YES;
img5.hidden=YES;
NSArray *array = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (NSString* aNumber in array)
{
   NSInteger i=[aNumber intValue];

  switch(i)
  {

        case 1:
            img1.hidden=NO;
            break;
        case 2:
            img2.hidden=NO;
            break;
        case 3:
            img3.hidden=NO;
            break;
        case 4:
            img4.hidden=NO;
            break;
        case 5:
            img5.hidden=NO;
            break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
NSArray *yourNumbers = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (NSString* aNumber in yourNumbers){
    NSString* anImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%@",aNumber];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. just one thing which is not clear is, as i said i hv 5 imageviews,and say they all are initially hidden. How can i show only those image which are associated to the output number. like i got 2,3,5 so only img2, img3,img5 only should be visible.?

Comment: Right way, give simple logic to it.@shishir.bobby check out my answer.

Comment: Sorry, must have missed that. Ishu improved my answer correctly, but you already noticed that :)